# C, Fork(), take CL argument and execute CHDIR

Tags: c, terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size); //define getcwd
char PATH_MAX[1024]; //define max size of path


int chdir(const char *path);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { // gets arguments when program ran, no arguments means argv=1

    pid_t pid; //process ID = pid
    pid=fork();
    char cwd[1024]; //compare directory to max character size

   if(pid==0){ //child has been forked! //child process created
    int ret;
    printf("Child PID=%d\n", getpid());
    getcwd(PATH_MAX, sizeof(PATH_MAX));
    printf(" My current working directory is: %s\n", PATH_MAX);

    ret= execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-a", "-l", "-h", NULL);
    printf("%d\n", ret); //why isn't this printed out?
   }

    //} 
   else {
    int status;
        //parent process
        //wait for child to complete
        printf("Parent PID=%d\n", getpid());
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1) {
            printf("ERROR");
        }
        else {
        printf("Child done.\n");
        getcwd(PATH_MAX, sizeof(PATH_MAX));

        printf("0");
        exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

I left my commented out code so you can see my thought process. If my understanding is correct the shell(terminal) is its own process so when you call fork, it creates a new child process and its parent becomes the shell. So trying to `chdir` in the child process will not translate over to the shell and you will remain in the same Directory so you would need to execute the `chdir` function in the parent PID, which is now the shell, yes?

I am having a hard time trying to figure out where exactly I should be putting this `chdir()` command and what flavor of exec I need to use to execute the terminal commands.

I am testing 3 different commands as command line arguments when running in terminal. This is after making the file with `gcc -o script script.c`

```
$ ./script 
 result - print out current directory
 print out "Usage: "<dir>" string. no command executed

$ ./script . 

result -"Executing ls . --all -l --human-readable" string

  executes above commands 

$./script / 

result - should execute above commands but change directory before 

executing

$./script /blah/blah

result - can't execute chdir

exit status: 1
```

I believe this code should cause the child process to return a `-1` which would terminate it, or if my if statement is correct it would print out the error message.

Any help would be appreciated, I believe I got the logic down, or at least somewhat. Just having a hard time implementing `chdir`.

Comment: Note that you don't "define" `getcwd()` — you only declare it.  You shouldn't need to declare it, though; the `<unistd.h>` header should be declaring it for you.  Similarly with `chdir()`.  You might need to specify `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or something similar to get the declaration visible — that depends on your compiler options and the platform you're working on.

Comment: All that commentary makes it hard to read the code.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Anything not relevant to your problem should be omitted.  Somewhere around half of the lines in your code are comments; that's a lot of comments!

Comment: Your notation `char PATH_MAX[1024];   //define max size of path` is odd.  Normally, `PATH_MAX` is defined by the system for you — if it is not defined, you should probably use `_POSIX_PATH_MAX` instead.  Either way, `PATH_MAX` is a number (used to specify the size of an array to hold a pathname), not an array of characters.  See POSIX [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html).

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I will edit my above code and remove the comments. I originally kept them on there so everyone can see what attempts I have made and if I was on the right track.

Comment: `exec()`-family functions only return if the exec process failed. If the call succeeded, the old program is no longer running (having been replaced with the thing that was exec'd) -- so that's why your *why isn't this printed out?* isn't printed out.

Answer (score 0):

I cooked your program a little and got the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])   // gets arguments when program ran, no arguments means argv=1
{
    int ret;
    pid_t pid; //process ID = pid
    pid=fork();
    char cwd[1024]; //compare directory to max character size
    char newPath[200]=".";
    if( argc > 1 )
    {
        strcpy(newPath,argv[1]);
    }
    ret=chdir(newPath);
    if( ret < 0 )
    {
        printf("Problem switching to :%s\n", newPath);
        perror("chdir");
        exit(ret);
    }
    if(pid==0){ //child has been forked! //child process created
        int ret;
        printf("Child PID=%d\n", getpid());
        getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
        printf(" My current working directory is: %s\n", cwd);

        ret= execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-a", "-l", "-h",  NULL);
        printf("%d\n", ret); //why isn't this printed out?
    }
    else {
        int status;
        //parent process
        //wait for child to complete
        printf("Parent PID=%d\n", getpid());
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1) {
            printf("ERROR");
        } else
        {
            printf("Child done. stat=%d\n", status);
            getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
            printf("Parent cwd:%s\n", cwd);

            printf("0");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Your understanding is not quite correct.  When you execute a program from the command line on a terminal, the shell forks and does an execute of the process you are running.  Normally, the parent shell process waits until the child process is done.  You created a child process and did another exec and another wait.  The parent shell patiently waits for you to finish, forked processes and all.

Let's see:

1. I put the `chdir` in your main program to show the child follows the parent.
2. A child process is not going to change the working directory of the parent.  Unix and Linux don't work that way.
3. When you run `execl`, that is it.  There is no return unless it can't do the execute.  The point of exec* is you are blowing away your currently running program with a new executable.  There is nothing to return to.
4. If you want to see the return code of the child, look at the status returned by the wait.  In this case, the `ls` ran fine so the return code is zero.  If you added a last argument of "baddir" (that is not there) you would see the `ls` non-zero return code, in this case, 512.